# On updating search params using useSearchParams hook, prev page gets loaded, how to prevent this from happening?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to update search params using `useSearchParams` hook after an async call. But if I navigate to another page before that async call gets completed then on finishing that async call, it tries to update the search params and takes back to the previous page.

Here is the sample code that I tried

```
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { useNavigate, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Assets = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const onPress = async () => {
    navigate("/trackers");
    const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/", {
      method: "GET"
    });
    await response.json();
    setSearchParams({
      assetId: "1"
    });
  };

  return (
    <List>
      <ListItem>test-asset-1</ListItem>
      <ListItem>test-asset-2</ListItem>
      <ListItem>test-asset-3</ListItem>
      <ListItem>test-asset-4</ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <Button onClick={onPress}>Press</Button>
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  );
};

export default Assets;
```

Here is the link to the sample project I created imitating this behaviour - [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-sky-ynm8iw)

I was expecting that only search params will get updated but it also goes back to the previous URL so I am confused. I am looking for the best way to handle this so that when we navigate to some other page then the search params shouldn't even get updated

Comment: This seems to be a possible bug with `react-router-dom`. I'm curious though, why navigate then immediately later try to update the queryString? Why not wait until the fetch completes and navigate with the desired search string value?

Comment: I did that just to imitate the behaviour and show the problem that I am facing. But essentially what I am trying to achieve is that if the user navigates to some other page (in this case `trackers`) before the fetching is complete then after the fetching is done he should not come back to the prev (in this case `assets`) page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly now, you only added the `navigate` call in the example to trigger the component to navigate away and the actual code isn't actually doing this.

What you can do is use an "isMounted" React ref to track when the `Assets` component mounts and unmounts, and check this in the `onPress` callback handler to conditionally update the search params.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Assets = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const isMountedRef = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    isMountedRef.current = true;
    return () => {
      isMountedRef.current = false;
    }
  }, []);

  const onPress = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/", {
      method: "GET"
    });
    await response.json();

    // if still mounted, update search string
    if (isMountedRef.current) {
      setSearchParams({
        assetId: "1"
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <List>
      <ListItem>test-asset-1</ListItem>
      <ListItem>test-asset-2</ListItem>
      <ListItem>test-asset-3</ListItem>
      <ListItem>test-asset-4</ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <Button onClick={onPress}>Press</Button>
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  );
};

export default Assets;
```

[image: Edit on-updating-search-params-using-usesearchparams-hook-prev-page-gets-loaded-how]

Comment: I guess we can use this functionality as a hook so we don't have to rewrite this logic every time but still I am wondering if this is the best way to handle this

Comment: @NitinAgrawal One other option I thought of afterwards was to use a cancel token for the inflight fetch request, and cancel the request when the component unmounts, but that won't be ideal if you want the request to process regardless what the user does in the UI. Using an "isMounted" ref is generally considered anti-pattern, but it's my opinion that in this case it is a valid edge case to the rule.